# MySQL my.cnf config for dedicated server

Tags: mysql, centos7, dedicated-server

we have a dedicated server hosting 1 website on it uses WordPress,

- CPU: Intel® Xeon® W-2145 Octa-Core (8-core)
- RAM: 128 GB DDR4 ECC RAM
- Connection: 1 Gbit/s-Port
- Traffic: Unlimited
- OS: CENTOS 7.6
- WHM/cPanel v76.0.17
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24

the website daily visits around 40K - 50K visitors it is a busy website! the problem is whenever website gets more than 1000 - 1500 active users the site response gets slow and slow and then the site goes down, I have contacted Cpanel support they checked the cPanel software they said this problem does not appear to be related to or caused by cPanel or by the basic configuration of the cPanel-bundled software. and they recommend me "Since your server has a large amount of free RAM available I would recommend dedicating more resources to Apache and MySQL as I see MySQL only has the default settings inside /etc/my.cnf" so I am looking for best my.cnf config this is my current server default config

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
performance-schema=0
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

performance-schema=0
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

performance-schema=0
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
```

I would really appreciate any help

and this is the result of mysqltuner :

```
[root@cpc ~]# ./mysqltuner.pl
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.14 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.24
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysqld.log(98K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log exists
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/log/mysqld.log contains 86 warning(s).
[!!] /var/log/mysqld.log contains 177 error(s).
[--] 7 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 2019-01-16T04:40:57.296462Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2019-01-15T23:34:47.207026Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2019-01-07T00:33:57.293154Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 2019-01-06T20:10:21.026368Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 2019-01-03T00:13:01.078628Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 2019-01-03T00:05:49.883857Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 2019-01-02T16:03:50.853606Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 2019-01-16T04:38:48.819118Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2019-01-15T23:34:44.152444Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 2019-01-07T00:25:29.383521Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 1.1G (Tables: 86)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 19.8M (Tables: 8)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 20h 6m 21s (29M q [414.302 qps], 474K conn, TX: 450G, RX: 3G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 99% / 1%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 156.9G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 338.9M
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 169.0M global + 1.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 175.8M (0.11% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 338.9M (0.21% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/29M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 3% (6/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.01%  (35/474804)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 27M selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (5K temp sorts / 12M sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 73% (1M on disk / 2M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (6 created / 474K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 60% (905 open / 1K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 7% (711/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (31M immediate / 31M locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Key buffer used: 100.0% (8M used / 8M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/267.0M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 97.6% (22B cached / 543M reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 85.8% (36K cached / 31K writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/19.8M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (75 %): 48.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (62131502 hits/ 62131969 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 0% (2 hits/ 0 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 2 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mysqld.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mysqld.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
    Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: 
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
[root@cpc ~]#
```

UPDATE: I have added following variables and not sure if this will effect anything to improve the performance !

```
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_limit=1M
tmp_table_size=17M
max_heap_table_size=17M
performance_schema=ON
```

and here is MySQL text results :

SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
https://pastebin.com/t6cKsLJz

SHOW VARIABLES;
https://pastebin.com/vu0KEXdd

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
https://pastebin.com/kpvVDU7D

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
https://pastebin.com/xtH3tD6w

and some additional checking for queries running most of the time !
https://pastebin.com/z7AsDjfD

More info!
https://pastebin.com/3ZGzXvMT

====================================

SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_posts :-

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
 `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_excerpt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
 `comment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
 `ping_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
 `post_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `post_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `to_ping` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `pinged` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `post_content_filtered` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `guid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `post_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
 `post_mime_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
 KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
 KEY `post_author` (`post_author`),
 KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
 FULLTEXT KEY `wp_greet_box_post_related` (`post_title`,`post_content`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=248367 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Run the mysqltuner.pl script.

Comment: I already did that !

Comment: Now you need to evaluate the results.

Comment: if only I could knew how , I'm not a MySQL expert that is why I am asking for help here :)

Comment: added text results for mysql show...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! sure i have added optional server information , and the server system installed on 1 TB SSD , 2x 1 TB SSD + 2x 10 TB HDD

Comment: @Bradosty This suggestion will give some immediate relief, 
SET GLOBAL read_rnd_buffer_size=131072; 
to reduce handler_read_rnd_next Rate Per Second which was 40984 in your SGStatus.

Comment: @WilsonHauck sorry for my late reply, i don't know why i can't upvote/accept your comments!!, after setting SET GLOBAL read_rnd_buffer_size=131072; and also tuning tmp_table_size +
max_heap_table_size both to 250M now website works much better duiring high traffic visits , which one made the response time better ? i am not sure. thanks again!

Comment: The one query in PROCESSLIST has not hit even 1 second.  Probe again.

Comment: I dispute the relevance of the dup -- That Question talks about generic capacity planning; this Question asks just about a WordPress installation.  I would expect a lot of WP-specific knowledge to exist.

Answer (score 1):

- Turn on the Slowlog to find out which queries are causing the most trouble
- Provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` for further analysis.

More details on how to do the above items:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

- Switch from MyISAM to InnoDB.
- Fix the `postmeta` indexes as indicated here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta
- Increase the settings below

Some setting changes (more may come with the SHOWs above).  Since you have a ridiculous amount of RAM, the following will be more than ample for before or after switching to InnoDB:

```
key_buffer_size = 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20G
```

Address further Questions to either the WordPress forum or stackoverflow.com; serverfault is for other stuff.

Comment: thanks! i have done some steps, question about ( Switch from MyISAM to InnoDB.) by this do you mean change the default-storage-engine=MyISAM to InnoDB or chnaging wp tables from PhpMyAdmin !?

Comment: sorry, should I convert all database tables to InnoDB or just _postmeta _sitemeta _comment...

Comment: @Bradosty - You should convert every one of your tables.  More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb .  InnoDB scales better, and has a number of other advantages.

Comment: @Bradosty - changing just the meta table would help some.  See all my tips.

Comment: do you have any idea why it wont let me chnage wp_posts to InnoDB i get this error ? 
SQL query:

ALTER TABLE wp_posts ENGINE = InnoDB
MySQL said: Documentation

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'post_date'

Comment: @Bradosty - What version of MySQL?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_posts`.  It is probably a change in a newer version having to do with defaults for `DATETIME` columns.

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper , and I have added the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE above

Comment: @Bradosty - Either change the default away from `DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` or use the sql_mode that allows "zero dates".  Meanwhile, gripe at WP for not fixing that.

Comment: `key_buffer_size` is for MyISAM, not for InnoDB. InnoDB's variable is called `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1217825/1066234